# aws sam build not able to build packages which require paramiko due to "Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, paramiko, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I've been learning the ropes with AWS SAM and have successfully deployed a number of lambdas together with dependencies and other AWS services. However, I seem to have run into a problem when trying to deploy a lambda which relies on some specific dependencies.

Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
paramiko==2.4.2
cryptography==2.6.1
bcrypt==3.1.6
pynacl==1.3.0
```

This file is found in "packageRoot/myCodeUri/requirements.txt"

When I run sam build I get the following error:

```
2019-08-27 11:18:18 Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies

Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {pynacl==1.3.0(wheel), cryptography==2.6.1(wheel), bcrypt==3.1.6(wheel)}
```

This (or at least similar) errors have been reported:[here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-builders/issues/71) over 8 months ago but is currently not answered.

P.S. I tried this originally with just paramiko as this is the only library my script uses, as I understood; the dependencies should be automatically pulled in during the build, however this didn't work either.

Any help would be great?

Comment: Have you tried running `sam build` with `--use-container`?

Comment: I have, but it throws a different error saying that it can't find the requirements.txt file. I also tried with the -m argument and manulally pointed to it but I got the same error.

Comment: Unless there is another way I should tell it the path to the requirements file? I get the feeling its a pip issue that could be resolved with upgrading pip - the problem (I believe) is the python 3.6 runtime is created with default settings for the build and you can't upgrade pip and then install paramiko in the same iteration through requirements.txt - if there is a way to build the container with pip already upgraded to the latest version then that may solve it? (I could be completely wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get a workaround to build and deploy lambdas that need the paramiko library using a docker container in interactive mode. Anyone having the same problem have a look [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1380)

Answer (score 13):

I was getting same error with another dependency while running `sam build`. I was able to resolve this by installing wheel in our python (or venv) environment.

```
pip install wheel
```

This approach did not require `--use-container` flag while running `sam build`

Comment: Weird that this solution was working for me before but not any longer since yesterday.

Answer (score 5):

Installing `wheel` didn't work for me, however upgrading pip did.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to use simplejson library. It was added to solve serialization issues... (pip wheel and upgrade didn't help), I just deleted the library and handle the serialization issues within the db query)